# AWS EC2 spot instance --block-duration-minutes not working

Tags: aws-cli

I was trying to request a spot instance using CLI. I used below command to request a spot instance:

```
aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price "0.050" --instance-count 1 --block-duration-minutes 120 --type "one-time" --launch-specification file://Spot_P2_request.json --query 'SpotInstanceRequests[*].SpotInstanceRequestId' --output text
```

I get below error:

```
Unknown options: --block-duration-minutes, 120
```

Is block-duration-minutes not supported by CLI?

Comment: Are you on the most up to date version of the CLI? That command works for me.

Comment: Try: `pip install awscli --upgrade`

Comment: Thank you. Updating awscli version resolve this.